# javascript/jquery ajax: what happens with inputs having same name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, http

Say I have a form that has some inputs that are linked to each other. Supposedly i run a pizza place where users submit a form with their pizza order. Each pizza order has a set of inputs that refers to an order: `type`, `option1` and `option2`. If a client wants more pizzas they can add another set of form inputs. The code below simulates an order for 2 pizzas:

```
<form action="pizza/get-now.html">
  First Pizza:
       <input type="text" name="pizza" value="quattro stagioni"><br>
       <input type="text" name="option1" value="extra bacon"><br>
       <input type="text" name="option2 value="no tomatoes"><br>

  Second Pizza:
       <input type="text" name="pizza" value="vegetarian"><br>
       <input type="text" name="option1" value="extra mushrooms"><br>
       <input type="text" name="option2 value="no cheese"><br>


  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If I'm using **`jQuery's serializeArray()`** I have some uncertainties:

1. does the server "know" [by default] that these inputs are grouped and they represent two orders? Is it something that comes with `serializeArray()`? I'm asking because on submit in the Network, all I see is the name and value pairs.
2. if not, what is the best way to deal with these types of grouped forms on the client-side (if there is one) so that the cheese-freak gets his/her fix?

Comment: you should create array of all fields like `pizza[]`, `option1[]` etc...

Answer (score 1):

> does the server "know" [by default] that these inputs are grouped and they represent two orders? Is it something that comes with 'serializeArray()'? I'm asking because on submit in the Network, all I see is the name and value pairs.

That depends entirely on the server and the format you send the data in. For example, in PHP you would need to append `[]` to the end of the field names for them to be collated. In C# MVC you'd need to define the model as having a `List<string>` property for each item, or better yet `List<Pizza>` and bind the pizzas as whole entities.

> if not, what is the best way to deal with these types of grouped forms on the client-side (if there is one) so that the cheese-freak gets his/her fix?

As an extension of the description above, it depends on your server side code, and the format it expects you to send the data in.

I realise this may not be the answer you were hoping for, but it's all that can be offered given the information in your question. In general though, `serializeArray()` does not help much when sending form data.

Comment: I have to configure the List<pizza> to receive something like { pizza: 'val', option1: 'val', option2: 'val' } for each of the input groups then? (I am using Spring but my question was more general because I assumed that i could control everything from the client - when building the data file

Answer (score 0):

To complete your approach, you should organize your form like this :

```
<form action="pizza/get-now.html">
  First Pizza:
       <input type="text" name="pizza[0]" value="quattro stagioni"><br>
       <input type="text" name="pizza[0][option1]" value="extra bacon"><br>
       <input type="text" name="pizza[0][option2]" value="no tomatoes"><br>

  Second Pizza:
       <input type="text" name="pizza[1]" value="vegetarian"><br>
       <input type="text" name="pizza[1][option1]" value="extra mushrooms"><br>
       <input type="text" name="pizza[1][option2]" value="no cheese"><br>


  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Note that this is assuming a PHP backend. The OP did not specify that.

Comment: isnt it better for the `.serializeArray()` ? I think the function 'merge' the input values (and take the last ones), in all case, the server wont have all the values so..